# Render output save as image in PHP

Tags: php, image, curl, mathml

I have code as

```
    <img src="http://www.wiris.net/demo/editor/render.png?mml=<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><mfenced open='[' close=']'><mrow><mi>d</mi><mi>f</mi><mi>g</mi><mi>d</mi><mi>dipen</mi><mi>g</mi></mrow></mfenced></math>"/>
```

If i put this code in browser i can able to see the one image. I need to store that image in my localhost. I tried GD,Copy(),Curl Image store but nothing helps me.

Please help me guys

Regards
Dipen

Comment: can you edit the code to a more readable format please :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Omar. If you put this link in browser  http://goo.gl/qaUcQ then you can see one image. I need to store that image in local. Is there any function available in PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this below functions:

```
function grabLiveImage($imgUrl,$pathToSave,$filename='')
{
    $data = file_get_contents($imgUrl);
    if($filename == '')
        $filename = getFilename($imgUrl);
    $fp  = fopen($pathToSave.$filename, 'w+');  
    fputs($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);    
    return $filename;
}
function getFilename($url)
{
    $basename = basename($url);
    $temp = explode('?',$basename);
    return $temp[0];
}
```

e.g. 
$url = 'http://www.wiris.net/demo/editor/render.png?mml=%3Cmath%20xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML%27%3E%3Cmfenced%20open=%27[%27%20close=%27]%27%3E%3Cmrow%3E%3Cmi%3Ed%3C/mi%3E%3Cmi%3Ef%3C/mi%3E%3Cmi%3Eg%3C/mi%3E%3Cmi%3Ed%3C/mi%3E%3Cmi%3Edipen%3C/mi%3E%3Cmi%3Eg%3C/mi%3E%3C/mrow%3E%3C/mfenced%3E%3C/math%3E';

grabLiveImage($url,'test/','test.jpg')

Comment: Hi Vibha .. Please check this link http://goo.gl/qaUcQ  . i need to store the rendered image in localhost. I tried your function but its not working.

Comment: http://www.wiris.net/demo/editor/render.png?mml=<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><mfenced open='[' close=']'><mrow><mi>d</mi><mi>f</mi><mi>g</mi><mi>d</mi><mi>dipen</mi><mi>g</mi></mrow></mfenced></math>

Comment: i have added your link in above post. It is working for me. What error you are getting?

Comment: You must have allow_url_fopen = On in your php setting.

Comment: its working good for me. One more thing is Here i have pass the math value "<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><mfenced open='[' close=']'><mrow><mi>d</mi><mi>f</mi><mi>g</mi><mi>d</mi><mi>dipen</mi><mi>g</mi></mrow></mfenced></math>" . How to change parameter like your parameter. I used urlencode(). its not create the image. Can you please help on this

Comment: its working good for me. I used rawurlencode(). then its working good.. Thanks Vidha .I appreciate that.

Comment: Select my answer. Click on tick arrow and make it green. :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript!

- Make a [Canvas](http://appcropolis.com/blog/javascript-encode-images-dataurl/) (drawImage).
- Get the DataURL - getImageDataURL( jQuery('img#yourimg').attr('src'), function(image) { ajax('post.php', image.data) });
- AJAX Request to Server, to save the DataURL to a File (file_put_contents('file.png', $_POST['data']))

Comment: http://www.wiris.net/demo/editor/render.png?mml=<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><mfenced open='[' close=']'><mrow><mi>d</mi><mi>f</mi><mi>g</mi><mi>d</mi><mi>dipen</mi><mi>g</mi></mrow></mfenced></math>

This is link. Here they wont give the image name directly.

Hope it will clarify. Please let me know if anything is not clear